# Having two dynamically selectInput in R shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I'm trying to create a interface that allows a user to choose how many columns to focus on, and then to choose a unique value in each column.

The code I have now does not match up the column value with the column name.  It does work when i only pick 1 column.  However, it does no work when there are >1 column.  The 'Choose Attribute ValueS' always resorts to the first 'Choose Attribute'.  I want them to be compatible.

```
 library(shiny)


ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(column(width = 4, 

    numericInput("assets", label = "Choose How Many Attributes to Produce in the Map:", value="1"),
    uiOutput("variants"),
    uiOutput("variants2")

    )


)))

server <-shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

  df<-read.csv("diff_block.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, colClasses="character")
  df$X<-NULL


  output$variants <- renderUI({
    numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)  
    lapply(1:(numAssets), function(i) {
          list(selectInput ("choose_columns", 
                        "Choose Attribute", 
                        sort(unique(names(df)), decreasing = FALSE),
                        selected=""))

    })
  })

    output$variants2 <- renderUI({
      numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)  



      lapply(1:(numAssets), function(j) {

      selectInput ("choose_columns2", 
                 "Choose Attribute Value", 
                 sort(unique(df[,input$choose_columns]), decreasing = FALSE),
                 selected="")
      })
    })
      })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were creating sliderInputs always with the same id  `(selectInput ("choose_columns", ...))`. The trick was to use `paste0` function to create widgets with different id's and then access their values using `[[` operator.

```
library(shiny)


ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(column(width = 4, 

                                      numericInput("assets", label = "Choose How Many Attributes to Produce in the Map:", value="1"),
                                      uiOutput("variants"),
                                      uiOutput("variants2")

)


)))

server <-shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

  #df<-read.csv("diff_block.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, colClasses="character")
  #df$X<-NULL
  df <- iris


  # output$variants <- renderUI({
  #   numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)
  #   lapply(1:(numAssets), function(i) {
  #     list(selectInput ("choose_columns",
  #                       "Choose Attribute",
  #                       sort(unique(names(df)), decreasing = FALSE),
  #                       selected=""))
  # 
  #   })
  # })

  output$variants <- renderUI({
    numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)
    lapply(1:(numAssets), function(i) {
      list(selectInput (paste0("choose_columns", i),
                        "Choose Attribute",
                        sort(unique(names(df)), decreasing = FALSE),
                        selected=""))

    })
  })

  output$variants2 <- renderUI({
    numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)  



  #   lapply(1:(numAssets), function(j) {
  #     
  #     selectInput ("choose_columns2", 
  #                  "Choose Attribute Value", 
  #                  sort(unique(df[,input$choose_columns]), decreasing = FALSE),
  #                  selected="")
  #   })
  # })

    lapply(1:(numAssets), function(j) {

      var <- input[[paste0("choose_columns", j)]]

      selectInput (paste0("choose_attribute", j), 
                   paste0("Choose Attribute Value of ", var),
                   sort(unique(df[ ,var]), decreasing = FALSE),
                   selected="")
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can print out all the columns or attributes that I picked in the drop down? textOutput? I not sure how to combine all the choices...  

output$roles22 <- renderUI({
    numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)
   xx<-data.frame()
     for (j in 1:(numAssets)){
      x =data.frame(input[[paste0("choose_columns",j)]])
      xx<-rbind.fill(xx,x)
    }
    tagList(
      helpText(paste0(xx)))

  }) #end of renderUIan't figure it out...